# Should I stick with my Stolen (brand) BMX or should I build my own bike?

Tags: bmx, build

I live in Greece and I am 13 years old. Recently I found a Flatland frame and thought about building my own bike. Should I build my own bike or should I stick with the [Stolen BMX](http://www.stolenbmx.com/) I already have?
I haven't tried to build one before so if you can give me some advice that would be nice. The frame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. As it stands, you're question is too opinion based for our [Q&A format](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  A better way to frame your question would be to ask about the relative advantages/disadvantages of the two brands you're looking at, or the advantages/disadvantages between building a bike or using the stock setup. You're welcome to do both, but please ask two separate questions. See our [help pages](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Gianis.

I'm an old man, but I used to ride BMX street and flatland years (decades) ago.

Because of their very specific geometry, Flatland frames are not great for anything but doing tricks.  If you need a general purpose bike for transportation and whatnot, stick with your Stolen (brand) BMX.

For those wondering, "Stolen" is the name of a BMX equipment manufacturer.
http://www.stolenbmx.com/

Comment: Lol what a bad company name:)

Comment: Bad is the new good.

Comment: It's "edgy" and "badass" :D